# Find the coordinate that gives the min y-value

Tags: matlab, plot

Let's say I have two vectors, same size.

Call it x and y.

I do a plot

```
figure
plot(x,y,'.')
```

It gives me some scatter plot. I see a minimum point on the graph. How do I extract that coordinate?

Should I combine the 2 vectors x and y and use `find` function?

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have

```
x = [9;8;7;6;0;5;4;3;2;1];
y = [0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9];
```

Then, you can do this:

```
[M, idx] = min(y);
min_point = [x(idx) y(idx)]
```

[MATLAB min](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html#bupsfee) documentation.

Comment: Is "M" and "idx" protected? What are they? What do (idx) do?

Comment: `M` receives the value of the `min(x)` and `I` receives the index of the element. I added a link to the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html#bupsfee).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[M, idx] = min(y);` ?

Comment: @LuisMendo my mistake